# Running a report by view + ID with AtTask API

Tags: attask

I see how to run reports based on the instructions given here: https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Report

The problem is that that method requires me to specify the columns, order, grouping, etc. in the code. I've already done that using the AtTask GUI. For example, I have a report that I can view by navigating to https://company-attask-url.com/report/view?ID=540f82490073dc256050c0575959c472.

Is it possible to retrieve the contents of that view? Otherwise, any time someone updates a report in the AtTask GUI, then I'll have to go in and update the code to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that I am wrong, but I don't think the report function works the way you want it to. To the best of my knowledge, the report function of the API doesn't have any connection to the reports that you create inside the AtTask application. It is just a way to ask for aggregates of columns such as average or sum.

Fields you ask for via the API are independent of fields set in a report inside the system. The good news for you is that you can just create what you want in the API. The fields shouldn't have to change for you to get your data.